# Express js - How to set variable in session?

Tags: javascript, express, express-session

I have a login form that ask to user, username, password and company name.
The company name is the database name, so in login post request I have to set database name in session.

I think the better option is in `session`, right? and not in `req.locals`.

For example, I tried to set with `req.locals` but don't work:

app.js

```
// Global Vars
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  res.locals.database = req.database || null;
  next();
});
// Express Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
```

And in `/login` post route I try to set like this:

```
req.locals.database = 'db_xpto';
```

And in view I tried to show the variable but don't show nothing:

```
h4 Using database: #{database}
```

Which is the better solution to do that, local variable or session? And how can I set that?

Note: In login I'm using `passport`.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, using a session is a better approach as it is automatically handled by the session middleware. Also `res.locals` is not available for the session but only for that request. You can modify your code to use session in the route directly instead of using an explicitly defined middleware.

```
  res.session.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.session.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.session.error = req.flash('error');
  res.session.user = req.user || null;
  res.session.database = req.database || null;
```

And you can do this in the same way in your login route as well.